# Is there any driver (64bit) available for Canon LBP6020B?

Tags: drivers, 12.10, kubuntu, printing, canon

I've have an i-Sensys LBP 6020B printer and I use Kubuntu 12.10 64-bit. I've a problem with drivers for Linux 64bit because I can't find anywhere capt linux driver - PPD file for LBP6020B. What am I supposed to do? My printer doesn't print.

Answer (score 2):

After several months of having problems with printers, because we migrated from Windows to Linux in our company which have more than 200 computers... now we found the driver which works on all our printers. The driver is **ljet4** , just found some similar model of printer with **ljet4** sufix on name and it will work. I wrote more on my blog : http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2013/01/driver-that-works-on-allmost-all.html

We didn't try on your model but every similar model we have worked very well.

Comment: I try with this drivers but it doesn't work :( I don't find my printer on the list. When I use a similar drivers from another printers it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[Link1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190)   [Link2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96970/how-to-make-the-printer-canon-laser-shot-lbp-1120-work-in-elementary-os-luna-ub) [Link3](http://random0musings.blogspot.com/2014/06/ubuntu-1404-and-canon-lbp6020b-laser.html)

I'm using Kubuntu 14.10. I tried to automatically start ccpd on startup as described in links. But it doesn't work always. So I need to run these commands before printing.

```
$sudo service ccpd start
$sudo service ccpd status
```

Following are some quotes from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190

> 1)  Configuring CUPS System->Administration->Printing add printer.
>   Choose "Add printer". Do not choose USB Printer found by Ubuntu here.
>   Select "CAPT Printer". You should see "ccp" in URI. Change it so URI
>   should become "ccp://var/ccpd/fifo0". Click "next", find your model
>   and add your printer. Choose English variant if you see Japanese and
>   English variants. Also If you do not have you exact model in list,
>   choose nearest. For example, for LBP 810, I choose "LBP 1120".
>
> To look for available models you may use command:
>
> $ find /usr/share/cups/model -name '*LBP*K.ppd' Close configuration
>   dialog, open again and rename your printer to, say, "LBP6020".
>   Remember name you chose, as later commands will refer to it.
>
> Instead of GUI actions, you may try this:
>
> sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP6020 -m CNCUPSLBP6020CAPTK.ppd -v
>   ccp://var/ccpd/fifo0 -E Again, choose another .ppd name, if you have
>   another printer...
>
> 2) 64-bit Systems Canon CAPT Printer Driver for 64-bit architecture
>   include the proprietary closed-source 32-bit executable captfilter
>   (called by pstocapt CUPS filter, used to convert PostScript data to
>   CAPT data stream) which depends on 32-bit libraries libc6 and
>   libpopt0. The libraries are not installed as dependencies. You can use
>   the following commands to check whether the captfilter is working:
>
> $ ldd /usr/bin/captfilter Messages like "not a dynamic executable" or
>   "libpopt.so.0 => not found" mean that your system affected by the
>   problem. For a workaround install the following packages:
>
> $ apt-get install libc6:i386 libpopt0:i386 Below is an example of working captfilter:
>
> $ ldd /usr/bin/captfilter linux-gate.so.1 (0xf76eb000) libpopt.so.0 =>
>   /usr/lib32/libpopt.so.0 (0xf76a6000) libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6
>   (0xf7501000) /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76ec000)